# Using XSLT to transform ReqIF to UML

Tags: xslt, uml, reqif

I'm trying to transform one XML document (REQ-IF) into another XML document (UML-Class-Diagram document) using XSLT.

My Problem now is the following:

REQ-IF provides datatypes as:

```
<Datatypes>
<DATATYPE-DEFINITION-STRING IDENTIFIER="xyz" LONG-NAME="ABC"
</Datatypes>
```

and Objects as:

```
<SPEC-OBJECTS>
<VALUES>
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-STRING THE-VALUE="some-value">
          <DEFINITION>
            <ATTRIBUTE-DEFINITION-STRING-REF>xyz</ATTRIBUTE-DEFINITION-STRING-REF>
          </DEFINITION>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-STRING>
</VALUES
<SPEC-OBJECTS>
```

This is resembled in my UML representation as:

```
<ownedAttribute xmi:id="some-ID" name="ABC" type="some-ID">
```

please note the ABC and xyz.

I therefore use <xsl:for-each> to loop through the Objects and another <xsl:for-each> to loop through the values. 
Now I have to take the Datatype-ID from the value, find out which Datatype it is and write the Datatype-name into the output file.
How do I do that?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Datatypes[DATATYPE-DEFINITION-STRING/@IDENTIFIER = current()/ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-STRING/DEFINITION/ATTRIBUTE-DEFINITION-STRING-REF]/DATATYPE-DEFINITION-STRING/@LONG-NAME`.

I admit I didn't actually test this, but you'll probably get the idea. The point of `current` is to access the XSLT context (the VALUES element) as opposed to the current XPath context that is active in the filter.